# Can't resolve domain names in Ubuntu with a static IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, internet, dns

Running Ubuntu 9.04 fully patched on a custom machine.  My typical setup is to assign static IP's to all my machines in the network (simplifies things with the other hardware).  This morning, my machine was doing fine and I was able to get out and about just fine,  Didn't make any configuration changes then.  Tonight, after I got home from work, I can't resolve domain names on my box, but I can get directly to IP addresses.  When I switch from using a static IP to DHCP, domain names resolve again and I can get out everywhere.  Does anyone know what would have changed to stop resolving domains, and how I can fix it so I can use static again?  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to try these as soon as I get home.

Comment: I had the same problem although I didn't have a static-IP, the accepted solution (to use OpenDNS) worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System > Preferences > Network Connections > Edit > IPx4 Settings > DNS Servers. Whatever is placed there, it does not work, maybe because your ISP started blocking external DNS traffic. Try to put there addresses of the OpenDNS nameservers, that is "208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220" without the quotes.

Does it help?

Another option is that the avahi daemon stopped working

Comment: The nameservers did it.  Actually sped up my response time too.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a DNS problem,try [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/)

Comment: OpenDNS appears to be a proxy service.  How would this solve a dns resolution issue?  If it were my wife's windows box, I could do a tcp/ip reset with the netsh command, but I don't know of a linux version.

Comment: no,they provide DNS servers,you can use them instead of your router's

Comment: Bad idea, they are lying DNS resolvers, which modify the legitimate responses (for instance to direct you to advertisments).

Comment: they do not do that,by the way

advertisements haven't changed when i used their DNS's

Answer (score 0):

When you say "all my machines in the network",
it seems you are referring to a local network at your home.
If that is correct interpretation, using static IP addresses in this network
that resolve on hostname (any common domain) requires 
[setting up the "`/etc/hosts`" file](http://jblevins.org/log/hostname).

Comment: have two computers, printer, ps2, and cell phones all connecting to the internal network.  everything with web browsers except my computer works just fine, not sure why ubuntu would need the hosts file set up since it's been running straight for a week without reboot and started sometime today during the day.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Google-dns server.

IP's are `8.8.4.4` and `8.8.8.8`, these work for me with arch Linux.